# Scan and Scroll Substitute in ElasticSearch version 2.x (NEST C#)

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Ive successfully used [Elastic 1.x scan and scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/scroll.html) with NEST API to get all documents matching my query. Started a new project and thought Ill use newest Elastic version 2.x, and stumbled on the first hurdle - how do I return all documents matching query (in c# using NEST)?

Any suggestions are appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1713) seems to indicate that scroll is still there and in the same way needs to be used.

Answer (score 5):

[`Scroll`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-scroll.html) is in Elasticsearch 2.x

synchronous version

```
var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    // specify a scroll time of 2 minutes using string,
    // implicitly converts to Time type
    .Scroll("2m")
    .Sort(ss => ss
        // sorting on "_doc"
        .Ascending(SortSpecialField.DocumentIndexOrder)
    )
);
```

asynchronous version

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<object>(s => s
    // specify a scroll time of 2 minutes using Time type
    .Scroll(new Time(2, Nest.TimeUnit.Minute))
    .Sort(ss => ss
         // sorting on "_doc"
        .Ascending(SortSpecialField.DocumentIndexOrder)
    )
);
```

More information on the [`Time` units](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/time-units.html)

Comment: how to get the all docs with one scan query? is it even possible? in the url you added above says "scroll API can be used to retrieve large numbers of results (or even all results) from a single search request".. but how? I couldnt figure out. when I define size larger than 1000, it will return error as search query. thanks

Comment: @batmaci scroll is a good way to get a large number of results, but ***you don't get all of the results in one request***; you need to request the next set of results each time using the `scroll_id` returned with the previous set of results. Think of the `scroll_id` as a forward only, read only, cursor over the result set

Comment: Does it cause any Performance impact on Index or shards if I scan entire Index which has around 100k documents? When i execute a scroll quero with size 10k,  i can see that it is  slow. Should I worry about the Performance if Same Index is used for a search on my Website. I read about memory usage is high but i am not sure.

Comment: There are a lot of factors to consider with regards to performance such as load, hardware, etc. that make it difficult to provide a clear answer there. The size on a scroll query is the number of docs ***per shard*** so bear that in mind. I would benchmark a few different sizes to see what works best in your case. Scroll with sort on `_doc` will be best performing way to retrieve all documents

Answer (score 0):

I am not a NEST user, but the way that scan and scroll queries are done has changed in ES 2.X. Now, you can do scan and scroll using a simple sort query based on _doc. Please refer to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
  "sort": [
    "_doc"
  ]
}
'
```

I hope I am helpful.